# WCF REST Passing JSONArray and Testing it on Fiddler

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, fiddler, wcf-rest

I have gone through much articles and questions but I am unable to resolve my problem. I am new to Fiddler and don't know how to use it. I want to pass List ob objects as an input in my WCF REST Service.

Here is my Service Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "LeadStage",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Result AddLeadStage(ReqLeadStage[] rls);
```

This is my **ReqLeadStage** class.

```
public class ReqLeadStage
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comments_Remarks__c { get; set; }
    public string Entry_Point__c { get; set; }
    public string Exit_Point__c { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Sequence_No__c { get; set; }
    public string Stage_Description__c { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedById { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Web.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
      <service name="SalesForceWCF.SalesForce" behaviorConfiguration="">
          <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SalesForceWCF.ISalesForce"/>
      </service>
  </services>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
      <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And this is my **Result** class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CODE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I ma calling it from Fiddler:
[image: POST Request]

And JSON:

```
[ { "attributes" : { "type" : "Lead_Stage__c", "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Lead_Stage__c/a009000000Rmb3wAAB" }, "Name" : "Discovery", "LastModifiedById" : "005900000028VWrAAM", "CreatedById" : "005900000028VWrAAM", "CreatedDate" : "2013-12-23T10:22:48.000+0000", "LastModifiedDate" : "2013-12-23T10:22:48.000+0000", "Id" : "a009000000Rmb3wAAB" }, ...... ]
```

This is a complete picture How I am sending my Request!
[image: Complete POST Request]

And this is the error:

[image: 400 Bad Request]

**400 Bad Request** Error. I am not able to trace it.

Thanks!

Comment: you can also try it using `RestClient` Mozilla add-on. Try via that. I'm not sure about the fiddler. In that I can help download that from here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/

Comment: you can try with Mozilla. Download it man . Its Free !

Comment: Its not working! Same error: 400 Bad Request! I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is there anything in response body ??

Comment: Server encountered an internal error. Isn't there any debugging tool?

Comment: Yes, you'll working on visual studio, then run the API in debug mode and when you'll submit your request from REST client it will gp to the starting point.

Comment: O Great! I really missed it! it is working now! Thanks kk :)

Comment: So either tell me the mistake you're doing so I'll make an answer and post that or you can post the answer. so it may help others.

Comment: It was at backend! When I was inserting data in to the database!

Comment: Fiddler can absolutely be used to debug this. Simply start by capturing a working request, then use the Composer to match that working request (headers, etc). There's nothing magical about the Mozilla REST client...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A per the discussion between me and [Faizan Mubashe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676700/faizan-mubasher) Here he comes to know that The problem was in database section.

Previously he was not able to figure out how he can debug the WCF service.

So the steps of doing that is simple

`dubug` your `service` and then make a `request` through `REST Client` **Add on from Mozilla**.

If that is not working properly then you can **go to debug menu -> attach a process -> find and select the REST Mozilla.**

This will **enable** the **Debugging** of `project/ WCF` rest Service.